# How to get the least path in kilometer distancematrix?

Tags: laravel, google-maps, google-api, distance

I want to get laravel routes between two points and choose the path with less kilometers ...

But the distancematrix returns me with the least amount of time ... what's your offer.

The code below is my code:

```
$response = \GoogleMaps::load('distancematrix')
        ->setParam([
            'origins' => $origin,
            'destinations' => $destination,
            'travelMode' => 'driving',
            'traffic_model' => 'pessimistic',
            'departure_time' => 'now'
        ])
        ->get();
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The response that you get contains `rows` array which then contains `elements` array. In there you have, `distance`, `duration`, `duration_in_traffic` and so on..

Something like this:

```
"rows" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "elements" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:4 [▼
      "distance" => array:2 [▼
        "text" => "2,527 km"
        "value" => 2526659
      ]
      "duration" => array:2 [▼
        "text" => "1 day 1 hour"
        "value" => 90807
      ]
      "duration_in_traffic" => array:2 [▼
        "text" => "1 day 7 hours"
        "value" => 111628
      ]
      "status" => "OK"
          ]
       ] 
    ]
]
```

So based on this you can filter/sort the results based on the distance value.

Comment: @Amin if I helped somehow, you can consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: but value duration_in_traffic not km and I get just a route